# Copy BOOST::Graph to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am obliged to use BOOST. Which is the easier way to copy BOOST::Graph to std::vector?

I would like to do something like this:

```
1. Create std::vector<float> v
2. for every vertex in the boost::graph g
     v.push_back(g.getDataofCurrentVertex());
```

I have read [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html) link, but still, I can't figure it out.

I would like to see the graph as just a container.

Comment: Kind of confusing that you are using `v` for both the vertex and the vector.

Comment: Typo @interjay, updated!

Comment: Afaik, there isn't any out of the box usable helper function in bgl which gives you back all of the properties associated with a bgl's entity, although i'm quite sure i've seen some dump() example once which would show how to do it. But basically, what you'd need is to access all the in- or exterior (or other kind of associated) properties for each vertex you like to "copy" and of course provide some storage where you want to put that data per vertex. Read more about the [boost property map library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html).

Comment: @wonkorealtime  I agree. However, Jason's solution seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to iterate through a DAG, you can use either a depth-first or a breadth-first traversal, the latter which requires a temporary queue.  You can read more about those algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Of course the BOOST graph data-structure implements a vertex and edge iterator for you ... you can iterate through all of the verticies using the `verticies()` function that they mention in the "Accessing the Vertex Set" section of the link you pointed to.  The example code for a simple traversal of all the verticies is in the code below it:

```
int main(int,char*[])
{
  // ...

  // get the property map for vertex indices
  typedef property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
  IndexMap index = get(vertex_index, g);

  std::cout << "vertices(g) = ";
  typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
  std::pair<vertex_iter, vertex_iter> vp;
  for (vp = vertices(g); vp.first != vp.second; ++vp.first) {
    //***replace this code with your vector::push_back() code ***
    std::cout << index[*vp.first] <<  " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know the algorithms. The problem is with BOOST. I just want to copy every vertex to an `std::vector' and I do not know how.

Comment: Okay, look at the sample code from the site ... I've just annotated it to show you where you can place your `std::vector` code in the `for` loop to get all the verticies into a STL container

Comment: You don't need to close the question ... try out the code sample and see if it works for you ... it should.

Comment: You saved me Jason. Thank you very very much. I will give you an upvote somewhere else too, because you answered a question done 7 days ago!